# How to upload pdf file only

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload pdf only not doc file if i use javascript code it will accept doc file
also

```
function CheckFile()
{
    var file = document.getElementById('FileUpload1');
    var len=file.value.length;
    var ext=file.value;
    if (file.value.length <= 0)
    {
        alert('Please select a file to import');
        document.getElementById('FileUpload1').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (ext.substr(len-3,len)!="pdf" )
    {
        alert("Please select a  pdf file ");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: And what happens if I disable JS? Validation should be serverside first, clientside second.

Comment: You can check for mime type & encoding as well / instead of checking file extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery or Javascript whatever you prefer.

Example for asp control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="PDFFiles" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AllowMultiple="true"/>
```

In document ready:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#' + "<%=PDFFiles.ClientID%>").attr('accept', 'application/pdf');
    })
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("<%=PDFFiles.ClientID %>").setAttribute('accept', 'application/pdf');
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no prefect solution to validate PDF file but what you can do is (on the server-side):

1. Validate **extensions** (pdf, doc, docx) *almost useless
2. Validate **MIME**
3. Open PDF file, read the header (first line) and check if it contains
   one of these strings: **%PDF-1.0, %PDF-1.1, %PDF-1.2,    %PDF-1.3,
   %PDF-1.4**

As an extra I also check if the file contains a
   string that specifies the number of pages by searching for multiple
   "**/Page**"

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing the actual upload with a FileUploadControl? If so a server side check (re: @Prisoner @WestDiscGolf) can be done, eg:

```
if (fileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType.Contains("pdf"))
{
   //continue processing
}
```

Pdf MIME types are supposed to be 'application/pdf' but you often get 'x-pdf'  too. Hence the contains.

Comment: it will accept all files (at the server) if their content type contains "pdf". The code I posted won't do anything client side - a postback is needed for the check to take place.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use asp code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Height="26px" accept=".pdf" /><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"
                        ValidationGroup="gr1" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1">pdf File Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regval1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="gr1"
                        ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z].*|[1-9].*)\.(((p|P)(d|D)(f|F)))$">Only Accept pdf </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadPDF" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" accept=".pdf" />
```

Comment: what if user selects file type all files in file selection dialog window ?