# how to check the uploaded file type is pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to check file types of uploaded files in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310714/how-to-check-file-types-of-uploaded-files-in-php)

I have uploading features on my site and only PDF uploads are allowed. How can I check that the uploaded file is only a PDF? Just like `getimagesize()` can verify image files.
Is there any way to check the file is a PDF? My code is below:

```
$whitelist = array(".pdf");

foreach ($whitelist as $item) {
    if (preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
        
    }
    else {
        redirect_to("index.php");
    }
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$uploadfile = mysql_prep($uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "succussfully uploaded";
}
```

Functions `redirect_to` and `mysql_prep` are defined by me. But mime type can be changed using headers. So is there any way to check the file to be an original pdf?

Comment: Why do you have an empty `if`? And please use proper indentation for your code or bad things will happen.

Comment: I just wanted to check is it maches or not..?

Comment: Simply do: `if (!preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) { redirect_to("index.php"); }`

Comment: this is not the answer @PeeHaa ..i have done this....how to check pdf entries just like getimagesize() function to check image files

Comment: Wasn't an answer, but it is a comment. I'm telling you how to improve your code :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309665/how-to-upload-pdf-file-only

1. Validate extensions (pdf, doc, docx) *almost useless
2. Validate MIME
2. Open PDF file, read the header (first line) and check if it contains one of these strings: %PDF-1.0, %PDF-1.1, %PDF-1.2, %PDF-1.3, %PDF-1.4
3. Check if the file contains a string that specifies the number of pages by searching for multiple "/Page"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check the MIME type of the file using PHP's [File Info Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). If it returns with the type 'application/pdf' then it should be a PDF.

The File Info Functions were added in PHP 5.3 but previous to that you are able to use the [mime_content_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function.

Comment: but if i have a php file and write(header: type="application/pdf")...than it will also show me the same

Comment: That's true, but that is less likely and it depends how critical this is

Comment: +1 that's only correct answer here. file info function provide a way to get **true*** mime type of the file

Comment: i want to overcome from my problem...the thing you are telling i have already checked that....Do you have any answer

Comment: i don't want the mime type...i want to check the content of the file and check that is it php or not.?

Comment: It should be noted that (as mentioned [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676272/1654898)) the `mime_content_type()` function has [not been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), and is explicitly mentioned as included in PHP7.

Comment: Correct, @BenEvans you may care to update your answer as this is a prominent but incorrect response, and it'll save a lot of hassle for people who don't need to install the extension.

(FYI, it seems there may have been a plan to deprecate it, but that's been reversed.)

Comment: I'd like to add that I hit upon a pdf-file which is a normal pdf-file in every way as far as I can tell, but mime_content_type($filename) as well as (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))->file($filename) returns "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 12):

Look for the PDF [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) by opening the file and reading the first few bytes of data. Most files have a specific format, and PDF files start with [%PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format).

You can check the first 5 characters of the file, if they equal "%PDF-", it is *likely* a real PDF (however, this does not definitively prove that it is a PDF file, as any file can begin with those 5 characters). The next 4 characters in a proper PDF file contain the version number (i.e. 1.2).

Comment: That's a VERY expensive solution! :D

Comment: Isn't this basically what the MIME type checks also do, but in a cheaper way?

Comment: Good point, it is essentially what a mime type check is probably already doing. But, if you do want to be more certain it is a valid PDF file (and you don't mind the extra processing time), you could scan the file for other expected constructs, such as the PDF "%%EOF" marker at the end of the file. (assuming this is more than what the mime check does)

Comment: that's a very insecure solution, I would replace the first few bytes with the bytes I want it to look like if I was trying to beat that protection. Very easy to do.

Answer (score 12):

```
mime_content_type('file.ext');
```

[mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: But please note that it [is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

Comment: @PeeHaa can you update your response?  This has not been deprecated. (See the link.) Maybe it was brought back to life?

Comment: The change has been reverted in [52d6b9aa9b0000744b727e4a596539371f06fd11](https://github.com/salathe/phpdoc-en/commit/52d6b9aa9b0000744b727e4a596539371f06fd11). PHP's bug site doesn't load at the moment, but once it is up again you can checkout  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71367 to see the reason for it. @daprezjer